# how can i bring content over the overlay? - CSS issue

Tags: css, position, overlay, z-index

The div tag has a background image and i wanna put the overlay on the main tag's background-image and the rest of contents over both of them. But The following code will put the overlay tag over the conent.

HTML:

```
<div id="nav-section">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <p>test</p>
        <h5>test</h5>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#nav-section{
background-image: url('../img/1.jpg');
background-position: top center;
background-size: cover;
position: relative;
}

#nav-section .overlay{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
height: 100%;
width:100%;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
z-index: 1;
}

#nav-section .container{
height: 600px;
}

#nav-section .container ul li{
float: left;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Make the `#nav-section .container` have an position relative or absolute with a z-index that is higher than the overlay.

Answer (score 1):

use z-index.

give #nav-section .container z-index that is higher then the div you want him to over lay.